# "não hajas tu" pode ser usado em que contexto?

Tags: tempo-verbal

Estava eu a ler o imperativo negativo do verbo haver: "não hajas tu", "não haja você", etc., quando tentei formar uma frase com "não hajas tu" e não consegui. A princípio achei que fosse por uma confusão sonora com "não ajas tu", mas não, realmente nunca usei o verbo haver nesse tempo.  Algum exemplo que faça sentido e seja de uso corrente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só com significados pouco usuais é que é possível conjugar o verbo *haver* no imperativo. Como verbo auxiliar (*eu havia chegado no dia anterior/hei de escalar o Evereste*) não admite o imperativo (ao contrário do verbo *ir*). O seu uso comum como verbo pleno é no impessoal com o significado de existir (*há estrelas no céu*), que também não permite o imperativo. Em todos os outros significados, o Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa classifica *haver* como pouco usado. Mas alguns destes significados admitem o imperativo, e aqui ficam uns exemplos:

> (a) ***Hajam-se*** vocês com ele. Eu não tenho nada a ver com isso.
>
> (b) Cuidado com o João. Não o ***hajas*** por tolo.
>
> (c) e não ***hajas*** medo que nos venha perseguir neste mundo aquela santa alma que está no Céu ([Almeida Garrett](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almeida_Garrett), [*Frei Luís de Sousa*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frei_Lu%C3%ADs_de_Sousa_(pe%C3%A7a_teatral)), 1844.)
>
> (d) ***Hajamos*** conselho sobre esta façanha, que Deus não nos há de leixar acuar ([Gil Vicente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gil_Vicente), *Auto da História de Deus*, 1527.)

*Haver* é usado em (a) com o significado de *entender-se, prestar contas*, de acordo com os significados 16 e 17 de [*haver* no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/haver) (a sua expressão mais habitual é *ter de se haver com*). Em (b) é usado com o significado de *tomar por, julgar* tal como no significado 3 do [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/haver). Não tenho a certeza que o exemplo (c) caiba na definição 6 do Aulete ou 1 do Priberam, mas está de acordo com o DACL, que dá como exemplo, "porque razão haveis receio?"

Answer (score 2):

Usos do imperativo negativo de haver são muito raros por duas razões:

- É incomum usar o verbo *haver* em sentido pessoal.
- Mesmo quando pessoal, *haver* não se conjuga na 2ª pessoa do singular do **imperativo afirmativo** (NGPC<sup>1</sup>, p. 446), o que tenderá a limitar os usos do imperativo negativo.

Pesquisando no [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), existem exatamente duas ocorrência de "não hajas":

> *[18:Garrett:Sousa]* João de Portugal nessa devota capela que é parte da sua casa; e **não hajas** medo que nos venha perseguir neste mundo aquela santa alma que está no Céu,
>   *[15:Barros:Asia3]* já leixei de engatinhar. Faze o que te digo, anda diante, **não hajas** medo. Indo per este modo o mais encobertamente que pôde, quando chegou onde

Existem outros usos do imperativo negativo na 2ª pessoa do singular, com "nam", "nom" ou "nem" em lugar de "não", mas vão todos na mesma linha: "não hajas receo", "não hajas dó", "não hajas preguiça".

Segundo Cunha e Cintra, este é um uso pessoal de *haver* incomum nos tempos modernos (NGCP, p. 533, ortografia original):

> É raro nos escritores modernos, mas muito frequente nos do português antigo e médio, o uso pessoal do verbo *haver*, como verbo principal, nas acepções de:
>     a) «ter», «possuir»:
>         Aos que o bem fizeram, **hei** inveja.

O exemplo é muito semelhante, mas não me parece que a descrição seja a melhor. "Haver" não significa "possuir" aqui, significa "experimentar", tal como nos exemplos do corpus acima.

Modernamente, onde o verbo *haver* é com mais frequência encontrado flexionado na 2ª pessoa do singular é como semiauxiliar na perífrase "haver de". Mas esta perífrase raramente é usada com o verbo haver noutros tempos que não o presente e o imperfeito do indicativo (ou o futuro e o futuro do pretérito, por vezes na escrita com significado semelhante). É possível encontrar exemplos no conjuntivo, mas o imperativo é incompatível com o significado da perífrase, em que, de resto, o presente já pode ter um valor modal de necessidade, quando usado na segunda pessoa:

> Tu hás de fazer o que eu te digo, quer queiras, quer não.
>   Hás de trazer-me depois um pratinho, por favor.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra. *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*. 1ª ed. Lisboa, Edições João Sá da Costa, 1984.</sub>

Comment: Encontrei em dois livros e em um site o verbo haver conjugado no imperativo afirmativo.  http://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-haver/

Comment: @Centaurus onde é que estão as passagens?

Comment: Artefacto,  no link abaixo, no livro "Breviário da Conjugação de Verbos" de Otelo Reis, e no "Português Básico" de Adriano da Gama Kury.   link -  http://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-haver/

Comment: @Centaurus Isso não é propriamente uma passagem. É a conjugação do verbo e não dá quase nenhuma informação sobre o uso.

Comment: Sim, Artefacto, é o verbo "haver" conjugado no imperativo afirmativo, de modo que acredito que ele seja conjugado em tal tempo verbal.